# Get Facebook public pages comments authors

Tags: facebook, api

[Since February 5th](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90), 2018 a page access token is required to get page comments authors.

> Starting on February 5th, 2018, for any comments or replies owned by (on) a Page, you must use a Page access token if you want User information to be included in the response.

I was wondering: how services like brand24.com still provide those informations?

My guesses are:

1. they have a page access token for each page results are coming from (I don't think so..)
2. they do scraping without using any api
3. they have access to a different kind of api (external provider or partners-only api??)
4. ..?

Any other idea?

Bonus question is: since having comments authors is not supported by public API, is this a policy violation?

Thanks

Comment: if it´s not possible with the api, it´s usually not allowed. scraping is definitely not allowed on facebook. so there is no allowed way to get the info.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard they get token v1.0 from m.facebook.com.
So they can have more data with old API.
But I can't remember how they get them.
Hope my keyword help for you.

Comment: This change is for all API versions. And v1.0 is not even available any more, so I doubt anyone would still be able to create “v1.0 tokens” now.

Comment: I don't think the change will apply to all version. Because old app build base on old version will not work.

Comment: Well have a guess why they call it “90-Day **Breaking** Changes” then ...

Comment: Thanks you. I've got it.